# Recursively check random element in array using coffeescript

Tags: recursion, coffeescript

I have a code base that was developed in coffee script, and as such am working to learn it.  Given an array of objects, how can I randomly select an object from the array, check if it's `is_available` property is true and return it's `name` property, otherwise remove the object from the array and recursively call the function again?

This is how I would do it in JavaScript.  I am not sure how to convert this to coffeescript though:

```js
var collection = [
    {name: 'Ford', is_available: true, color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'Toyota', is_available: false, color: 'green'},
    {name: 'Honda', is_available: false, color: 'red'}
];

var findItem = function(arr, prop) {
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var item = arr[position];

    if (arr.length === 0) {
       console.log(arr.length, 'Array is empty.  Ending!');
       return;
    }
    else if (item[prop] === true) {
        console.log('Found one!',item.name);
        return item.name;
    }
    else if (item[prop] === false) {      
      arr.splice(position, 1); //Remove item from the array
      console.log(arr);
      return findItem(arr, prop); //Recursively call function again.
    }
};

findItem(collection, 'is_available');
```

Comment: @muistooshort you're absolutely right.  I editted the code sample and removed it.

Comment: Are you asking what coffeescript would like for this code? (http://js2.coffee)

Comment: @jcuenod Yes.  I've been looking into coffee script, but I'm not sure how do handle the condintionals and the recursive call to the function.  It was easier for me to write the JavaScript version, but if it would help I can try to produce what I can with coffeescript.

Comment: CoffeeScript is Javascript. Just with a reduced syntax. You can write exactly the same code you have above in CoffeeScript, merely translating the syntax as necessary. There may or may not be more concise shortcuts you could take in CoffeeScript (list comprehension and such), but ignoring that for the time being, what problem exactly do you have translating this syntax to CoffeeScript?

Comment: See here: http://bit.ly/1J2cVas (shortened link to js2coffee)

Comment: @jcuenod Thanks for the link!  This tool will really help!

Comment: @deceze I have learned that it's just syntactic changes.  I don't quite understand how to call a function in coffeescript.  The example I made has a lot of pieces, variables, condition statements, arrays, objects, and recursion. I was thinking that translating this would be a good way to get familiar with coffeescript, but I'm not sure how to call a function recursiely.  It looks like jcuenods link can translate it though :)

Comment: You call a function exactly the same way as in Javascript: `func(arg1, arg2)`. You can *optionally* leave out the parentheses: `func arg1, arg2`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @deceze: The parentheses are optional in *some* cases and never when the function doesn't have arguments. Some people contort their whitespace in an attempt to never see the scary parentheses, some people always put them in. And of course, `f(x, y)` and `f (x, y)` are different things.  It is a bit of a mess really, just like it is in Ruby.

Comment: @muis Sure, that statement about parentheses comes with a bunch of asterisks. Personally I leave them out whenever possible without having to change anything else. If you need 'em you need 'em, when you don't you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user requirement is to get a random element such that a predicate holds, `Array::filter`  is probably better -

```
filterItem = (arr, prop) ->
    filteredColl = arr.filter (elem) -> elem[prop]
    filteredColl[Math.floor(Math.random()*filteredColl.length)].name
```